# How was the closed form of $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(n-i-j+2)$ calculated?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, closed-form

I am struggling to understand the closed form calculation of the following triple summation:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=i+j-1}^{n} 1
$$

The first step I understand:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=i+j-1}^{n} 1=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(-i-j+n+2)
$$

But the next steps are what confuses me.

$$
=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(-i-j+n+2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(i-n)(3 i-n-3)\right)
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2}(n-1) n
$$

I would like to know, in excruciating detail, how
$$
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(-i-j+n+2) = \frac{1}{2}(i-n)(3 i-n-3)
$$

Comment: The first step is not true, however, when $i+j-1>n$. For example, when $i=n$ and $j=n$, you are saying that $\sum_{k=2n-1}^n 1=3-n$. However, this sum should evaluate to $0$ since the upper bound is smaller than the lower bound.

Comment: @AlanAbraham This may be besides your point, but wouldn't it be $\sum_{k=2 n-1}^{n} 1=2-n$ ? Also, how could $i=j=n$, $j$ must be $i+1$. Lastly, in this particular instance, the lower bound is greater than the upper bound, so there are no summands, which is defined to be $0$ anyway? My thought here is $3-n$ wouldn't be evaluated anyway, and it is defined to just be $0$.

Comment: There was some oversight in my provided example. Instead consider $i=n-1$ and $j=n$. Then you are saying that $\sum_{k=2n-2}^n=3-n$ when it should be $0$. Lastly, there might be a misunderstanding between us, but I am agreeing that it should be defined as $0$, but $3-n$ is not equivalent to $0$, so you are not summing it properly. You probably will need to redefine the limits so that you exclude any improper summing from happening because it will not automatically be excluded when you use the summation identities that you are using.

Comment: @AlanAbraham thanks for your quick response, I think I understand now.. do you know offhand of any good resources to understand this particular topic better?

Comment: No, I personally do not know of any resources. However, I am sure that there do exist resources somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r=j-i$, then $j=r+i$ and
$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(-i-j+n+2)&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-i}(-2i-r+n+2)\\
&=-\sum_{r=1}^{n-i}r+(n+2-2i)\sum_{r=1}^{n-i}1\\
&=-\frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}+(n+2-2i)(n-i)\\
&=\frac{(n-i)(-n+i-1+2n+4-4i)}{2}\\
&=\frac{(n-i)(n+3-3i)}{2}.
\end{align}$$
which is the equal to $\frac{1}{2}(i-n)(3 i-n-3)$.
As regards the last sum, let $j=n-i$, then $i=n-j$ and
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(n-i)(n+3-3i)}{2}&
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(3j+3-2n)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j^2+\frac{(3-2n)}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\\
\end{align}$$
Can you finish the job?

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(-i-j+n+2)
&=\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(-i+n+2)-\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}j\\
&=(n-i)(n-i+2)-\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}(j+i)\\
&=(n-i)(n-i+2)-\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}j-\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}i\\
&=(n-i)(n-i+2)-\frac12(n-i)(n-i+1)-i(n-i)\\
&=(n-i)\left((n-i+2)-\frac12(n-i+1)-i\right)\\
&=(n-i)\dfrac{2(n-i+2)-(n-i+1)-2i}{2}\\
&=(n-i)\dfrac{n-3i+3}{2}\\
\end{array}
$